# Is there a way to change VBA code to open a specific folder instead of file explorer for importing files?

Tags: excel, vba, file, import

This problem might have an easy solution, but I cannot get it to work. I`d like to open a specific folder to run the following section of the VBA code:` Sub ImportText3()

```
Dim ThisLine As Variant
Dim fileFilterPattern As String
Dim n As Long

' Just look at text files
'fileFilterPattern = "Text Files *.txt,*.txt"
fileFilterPattern = "Text Files (*.txt; *.csv),*.txt;*.csv" 'use this line for general txt file selection
ThisLine = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilterPattern)

If ThisLine = False Then
    MsgBox "Did not select files from Josue`s folder."
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Open ThisLine For Input As #1`
```

Instead of opening the file explorer, I want it to open a specific folder, which is what excel is doing.

I tried using  `fileFilterPattern = "C:\Users\jcriollo\Documents\Bronx\Raw Data\05.23"` as my file path insteasd of having `fileFilterPattern = "Text Files (*.txt; *.csv),*.txt;*.csv"`, but the code is giving me bugs. Is there a simple way to change this?

Comment: Have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5Dopen+a+specific+folder).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible ways:

**1. Change Excel's working folder.**

Before you display the dialog box, execute this line (using your desired folder path):

```
ChDir "C:\YourFolder\"
```

Note that this will change Excel's working folder for the session.

**2. Use a `FileDialog`.**

Try this:

```
Set FileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
FileDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\YourFolder\"
result = FileDialog.Show

If (result = -1) Then MsgBox FileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
```

You will need to adapt this to your needs - documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog).

The main advantage of the second approach is that it affects only the dialog box displayed, not the whole Excel session (i.e. Excel's working folder remains unchanged).

Comment: Thank you. I used the first solution for simplicity, and it works! I`d like to know if I can add another dialog box that would say something like "Change your file path" if the folder is not found? I tried just like what I did for the "no file selected" but I guess it doesn`t work as a variable